# Why is docker image is too big? NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, docker

I am building my app into docker image.

My docker file:

```
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./package.json ./package.json

RUN yarn

COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./gulpfile.js ./gulpfile.js
COPY ./tsconfig.json ./tsconfig.json

RUN yarn build

RUN rm -rf ./node_modules
RUN rm -rf ./src
RUN rm -rf ./gulpfile.js
RUN rm -rf ./yarn.lock
RUN rm -rf ./package.json
RUN rm ./tsconfig.json

RUN cd dist && yarn 

CMD ["node", "./dist/boot.js"]
```

After build I opened docker image and found my app in `/user/app/dist` size is 264MB (including node_modules).

But docker image has `867MB`.

Why?

is there anything wrong in my dockerfile script? I am using node alpine, it should be small.

Comment: I would recommend a multi-stage build, and then you can install only prod dependencies in the second stage. See e.g. https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: WITHOUT my app docker container have (867-264) **603MB**, I think it is not about prod dependencies. It is normal container size?

Comment: `node:12-alpine` on my machine is ~80Mb, so I don't know what you've got.

Comment: Using which command did you get the size of the image?

Comment: I list my images using `docker image` and ther is a SIZE info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding lines to a Dockerfile never makes an image smaller.  Because of the way an image is constructed from layers, a `RUN` line generally results in everything from the previous layer, *plus* whatever changes result from that `RUN` command.

As a specific example in your Dockerfile:

```sh
# Build the contents of the dist/ directory
RUN yarn build

# Keep the entire contents of the previous layer
# PLUS add markers that the node_modules directory should be removed
RUN rm -rf ./node_modules
```

As @jonrsharpe points out in comments, you're probably looking for a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).  The basic concept here is that a second `FROM` line will cause `docker build` to completely start over from a new base image, but then you can `COPY --from=` a previous stage into the final stage.

You might rebuild your existing image like so:

```sh
# Add "AS build" for later use
FROM node:12-alpine AS build

# This is exactly what you had before
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY ./package.json ./package.json
RUN yarn
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./gulpfile.js ./gulpfile.js
COPY ./tsconfig.json ./tsconfig.json
RUN yarn build

# Now build the actual image, starting over.
FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist .
# but not its node_modules tree or anything else
CMD ["node", "boot.js"]
```

Comment: Oh, I am on it. Thank you. Now it is final image smaller! Final size is 272MB (there are a lot of packages in node_module folder)

Comment: Thanks, for me it went down from 267MB to 149MB